# C++: Cannot move a file, because of a space on folder's name

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using `movefile()` to move a file to a specific folder,
but when I try to do it, it doesn't work because there's space in the folder's name "New Folder"
but if the folder's name doesn't have spaces it works

Here's the example (Without a folder that contains a space on its name) :

```
std::string input1 = "C:\\Users\\Username\\link.txt";
std::string input2 = "C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\NewFolder\\link.txt";
MoveFile(input1.c_str(), input2.c_str());
```

And there's the example when there's a folder that contains a space

```
std::string input1 = "C:\\Users\\Username\\link.txt";
std::string input2 = "C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\New Folder\\link.txt"; //here's the folder
MoveFile(input1.c_str(), input2.c_str());
```

I'm not getting any syntax error, but I'm pretty sure, it doesn't works because of this space between **"New"** and **"Folder"**

Any way to fix it?

Comment: So MoveFile returns false? If so check GetLastError() for the reason.

Comment: You almost certainly do not need all those backslashes - just because things like cmd.exe use them doesn't mean your C++ library needs them.

Comment: Paths with embedded strings should also include quotes.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773739(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @stark - absolute no. not need any quotes on space

Comment: @NeilButterworth: in C and C++, '\' is an escape character inside a string literal, so if you want an actual '\' character, you have to escape it as '\\'.

Comment: @stark: RbMm is correct.  Quotes are needed for parameters on a command-line, but are not needed for API function calls that take path strings as input.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I think Neil meant the path passed to `MoveFile` can use forward slashes.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing the error code (GetLastError) that you're getting when this fails.  I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Most important thing is that OP replies to the first comment. Otherwise this question should be closed because we can only do guesswork.

Comment: @Remy My point is that most C++ libraries on Windows do not require backslashes as path separators.

Comment: @eryksun: most path functions in the Win32 API do not accept forward slashes.  Some shell functions do.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: *If* you use a wrapper library at all, it would have to translate slashes internally to conform to Win32 API requirements.  Since the OP is clearly using the Win32 API directly and not a library, this matter is moot for this situation.

Comment: @Remy Things like CreateFile() certainly understand forward slashes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I've had my share of surprises with the path handling functions. But if you're not using that subset of the API, then it's not an issue. The filesystem API does translate slash for you (except for ``\\?\`` paths). In Python, for an example of a "wrapper library", we don't rewrite paths passed to `open` and `os` functions to replace slash with backslash, because the APIs we're calling support forward slash. It all depends on context.

Comment: @Remy And so does MoveFile -  I just tested it.

Comment: all win32 api for files used common function for translate win32 path to ntpath `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U` and this api usuallu translate / to \, except \\?\ prefix

Comment: @RbMm, or sometimes it calls `RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U_WithStatus`. But the NT runtime library functions are an implementation detail with respect to the Windows API.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, can and `RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U_WithStatus` or it internal subroutine, but this not change main - exist common api for translate.

Comment: @RbMm, what matters is the documented behavior of the Windows API. People need to hound Microsoft more to improve their WinAPI documentation; update it and fix mistakes. For example, this section on the [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247#maxpath) still has the wrong group policy name "Enable NTFS long paths" instead of "Enable Win32 long paths", which I've seen confuse devs into thinking this feature is only available for NTFS volumes, and also it's still not clear that it requires enabling at both the system level and in the app manifest.

Answer (score 6):

### I can't reproduce the failure.

With my project configured for ANSI/MBCS instead of Unicode (thus allowing `std::string::c_str()` to be passable to the `TCHAR`-based `MoveFile()` macro), the exact code shown (only replacing the `Username` with my own) works perfectly fine for me.  `MoveFile()` returns TRUE, and the file is actually moved.

```
std::string input1 = "C:\\Users\\<my username>\\link.txt";
std::string input2 = "C:\\Users\\<my username>\\Desktop\\New Folder\\link.txt";
MoveFile(input1.c_str(), input2.c_str()); // <-- SUCCEEDS
```

So, the problem has to be elsewhere.  Either:

- the source file does not exist, or is inaccessible.
- the destination folder does not exist (`MoveFile()` will not create it for you! Use `CreateDirectory()` or similar function beforehand), or is inaccessible.
- there was an error while moving the data.  Which is rare on a NTFS filesystem, as moving a file from one folder to another folder on the same drive will just relocate the file reference and not move the actual file data.

If `MoveFile()` returns FALSE, you need to call `GetLastError()` to find out why it fails.